# Giving owner to MessageBox which is getting called from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, cefsharp

I am using `CefSharp 37` in `winforms`. I have implemented `IRequestHandler` and want to write some `ResourceHandler` code in method `OnBeforeResourceLoad`.

in `OnBeforeResourceLoad()` I check some condition and on that basis I display a `MessageBox` with OK and Cancel buttons. By pressing `Cancel` I want to return `true` otherwise `false`. Code as below:

```
    public bool OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser browser, IRequest request, IResponse response)
    {            
            if (!request.Url.Contains(ContentHelper.requestTrapKey)
            {                    
                var handler = browser.ResourceHandler;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler.RegisterHandler(request.Url, ResourceHandler.FromStream(File.OpenRead(ContentHelper.contentRootPath), Path.GetExtension(ContentHelper.contentRootPath + final));                        
                }
            }
            else if (!request.Url.Contains(ContentHelper.requestTrapKey + "course") && request.Url.Contains(ContentHelper.requestTrapKey))
            {                      
                if (MessageBox.Show("message", "title", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    return true;
                }                  
            }

        return false;
    }
```

It is observed that sometime `MessageBox()` goes behind to main form and user waits for messagebox to come and also next code also in wait state to execute. I know that as `MessageBox.Show()` is called on other thread than main thread so that's why it's going behind.

So is there any way where I can show `MessageBox` or a message to user without going it behind and take input from user and accordingly return true or false to load resource.

**Update**

I tried as @Adil said in answer to wrap the code by `MethodInvoker` then `MessageBox` remain on top of form but as **when I press any button on message box application get hanged.**

I have written an parametrized constructor of MyRequestHandler class as :

```
    public MyRequestHandler(MainForm mainform)
    {
        this.mainform = mainform;
    }
```

Then as said by @Adil :

```
bool returnValue = false;
mainform.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => 
{
     if (MessageBox.Show(mainform,"message", "title", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Cancel)
     {
         returnValue = true;
     }
}));
return returnValue;
```

Answer (score 3):

> I tied with checking InvokeRequired of mainform but still it's
>   throwing same exception.

You not only need to check the InvokeRequired but you need to invoke on GUI thread. You can do that by using [`MethodInvoker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you have return with `MethodInvoker` delegate it will return from delegate instead of the method having `MethodInvoker`. You can set value of some bool variable to true, which you can use after delegate finishes its execution to *return* from the method.

```
bool returnValue = false;
mainform.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => 
{
     if (MessageBox.Show(mainform,"message", "title", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Cancel)
     {
         returnValue = true;
     }
}));
return returnValue;
```

Comment: Is it necessary to keep this code inside `if` which checks  `mainform.InvokeRequired`?

Comment: Its not necessary but if you do that you will get little performance benefit as you will have less code to execute  if InvokeRequired is false.

Comment: ok I surrounded code with `if`, but I observed that after 3-2  `MessageBox` application get hang, Why it is? If I remove owner object (mainform) from `MessageBox` then all works fine but sometime `MessageBox` goes back to main window as `MessageBox.Show()` is called on other thread.

Comment: I do not know what is going on in your form. You might need lock if you have multiple threads. If it is so, read about lock, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: after adding `lock` same is happening. I updated question and explained in detail.